# "TF14045: The identity <guid> is not a Recognized identity" after atach project collection from TFS 2010 to 2012

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I am not able to access both the Source control in Visual Studio 2010 as in 2012 when I try to access this error is shown:  "TF14045: The identity  is not a Recognized identity".  This error started after I detach the project collection from TFS 2010 and attach on Team Foundation Server 2012,  anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have TFS 2012 with Update 1 installed? If so you have to wait for the upcomming patch that will contain a bugfix for this error. Have a look at Microsoft Social:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/238cad96-8e74-4f14-869a-3bb5e0629fd7

Comment: I just ran across this issue,  I have VS 2012 with Update 3,  and connecting to TFS 2012 ,  It is happening on a viewing history of a few controllers so far

Comment: @TomStickel So what is the current patch level on your TFS?

Comment: On this current project i'm working remotely and currently just connect to TFS via both VS 2012 and then I also use their TFS website for tasks and bugs.  I don't know where I would see or find that information. Do you?  Or do I have permissions?  Where should I look ?

Comment: @TomStickel You need admin access to the TFS. Just contact the responsible administrator.

Comment: One my users is having this issue as well with TFS 2012 with update 4 installed

Comment: And again someone is downvoting without leaving a comment. Thanks a lot for giving me no chance for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Never had this error, because the migration is planned for January, but I found this entry with some suggestions and answers from MS:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/b67ad1d6-d763-4602-bf14-489a3389a30d

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure that you have not opened two instances of Visual Studio & trying to connect two TFS servers which needs two different credentials/ domain.

I was facing that issue & after closing one of the instances, it started working fine.